# How to change the resolution of a WMV file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, video

I have a C# application and I would like to be able to read in a WMV file and then write out a WMV file with reduced resolution/quality.

Are there any built-in libraries for C# that can do this? Do I need the Windows Media Format SDK?
Does anyone have experience with this?

Can I use something like FFmpeg for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to decode and re-encode ( = transcode) the file to do this. By doing so you will inherently reduce quality since you are working off an already compressed base.

One way to do it if you need a high degree of control is is with a DirectShow wrapper for C#, i.e. [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/). then you just need to define a simple transcoding graph.

Actually the simplest way to do this is with [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/EncoderPro_Overview.aspx) (the successor to Windows Media Encoder) which has a simple managed API and should do the job with much less effort than integrating DirectShow.

There's a summary article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714558.aspx). A simple transcoding job looks like this (sample from article, only presets changed):

```
      MediaItem src = new MediaItem
          (@"C:\WMdownloads\AdrenalineRush.wmv");
      Job job = new Job();
      job.MediaItems.Add(src);
      job.ApplyPreset(Presets.VC1WindowsMobile);
      job.OutputDirectory = @"C:\EncodedFiles";
      job.Encode();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any classes in the .Net Framework which deal with transcoding WMV files.

But you can install the [Windows Media 9 Encoder SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=000A16F5-D62B-4303-BB22-F0C0861BE25B&displaylang=en) and create appropriate objects in C# to do the conversion. See [CodeProject.com - Convert MP3, MPEG, AVI to Windows Media Formats](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/ConvertVideoFileFormats.aspx) for a starting point. Even though that link starts with non-WMV files, the Windows Media Encoder doesn't restrict the input file format (at least when I've used the VBScript encoding batch file).

N.B If you use the WM9Encoder on Vista or Win7, you may need the hotfix - see [TechNet - issues in using Windows Media Encoder 9 Series on Windows 7](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/8534bc53-8979-45df-a5ff-8def93e38332)